# Update function gives error

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I want to update a column in the DataBase from '1' to '0'. For that I've made an update function. But when I run the query i get a strange result..

Before clicking on "accepteren"
[image]

After clicking on "accepteren"
[image]

The first tabel disappears and the value of status doesn't change in the database

My function is:

```
   public function accept(){

  // Update query
 //*
     global $wpdb;
     $wpdb->query($query);


             $query =($wpdb->prepare("UPDATE " . $this->getTableName() .
                    " SET `status` = 0 WHERE `wp_ivs_canvas_tabel`.`id` = %d", $id));

}
```

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: pass value in prepare() for %d

Comment: @MKhalidJunaid What do you mean exactly? i'm a bit new with this

Comment: Have a look at [wpdb::prepare( string $query, array|mixed $args )](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wpdb/prepare/)

Comment: @MKhalidJunaid I have tried a few times but still the same result..

Comment: echo "UPDATE " . $this->getTableName() .
                    " SET `status` = 0 WHERE `wp_ivs_canvas_tabel`.`id` = ".$id;

Comment: and check the query